# Setting a default value od select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am making a jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap app. I am dynamically loading a select menu's options. I want the first option to be the default "value" of my select menu. After appending, I have all my options, but none of them is already chosen. I tried refreshing and setting value attribute, but it doesn't work. Here is my javascript:

```
function customerList(data)
{
  var html ='';
  console.log('Start');
  $.each(data, function(key, value){
    html += '<option value="'+ data[key].id + '">' + data[key].label + '</option>';
    $('#customer').append($(html));
    html='';
  });
  $('#customer').selectmenu();
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the `value` attribute of your `<select>` element?

Comment: I am setting value in pageinit event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting

```
$('#customer').val("optionValue")
```

will work

Comment: I have it in my pageinit event

Comment: You need to add it to the end of the customerList(data) function. Or at least it needs to be executed AFTER the dropdownlist was populated.

Answer (score 0):

also work with *selected* atribute (selected="selected").
But first you need to identify the default option in your each loop

Comment: reply with more specific answer